# disappearing vs disappearance

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Climate change causes the rise of sea levels, the **disappearance/
>   disappearing** of certain plants and animals.

I got the question: which one is correct in the sentence above between 'disappearance' and 'disappearing'.

I know 'disappearance' would be the right answer but
I'm not sure about 'disappearing'.

Comment: That sentence isn't grammatical no matter which word you use.

Comment: @JasonBassford How so?

Comment: There's a comma splice, and it's not clear exactly what the relationship is between the text before and after it. It would make sense if the comma were replaced by, for instance, *and* or if *which leads to* were added after it. There are some other things that could fix it. But it's not clear what's being said as it stands.

Comment: @JasonBassford Maybe that needs more.  As it stands, the sentence could be understand to be saying that "the rise of seal levels" is the same as "the disappearance of certain plants and animals."  That's because it has the structure  A <some action on> B, C.   Another example "You should meet my wife, Morgan Fairchild."  Does it mean you should meet my wife and a completely other person called Morgan Fairchild? Or does it mean you should meet my wife who is Morgan Fairchild?

Comment: What do you mean: I got this question? I have this question? I found this question? Somebody asked me this question: the disappearing of x=the disappearance of. But your sentence is not well written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I should assume thate your statement merely seeks to establish a causal claim between climate change and sea rise and disappearance(-ing)- then I'll confidently say both option as disappearance ( which is in a complete state) and disappearing( which is in itself an ongoing phase) , in fact, are technically correct; the only problem is; I still don't get what you wanted to put across- as I saw a comma in the statement. nevertheless both options are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either you left out part of the sentence or whoever wrote the test has an ironically poor grasp of grammar. Either way, both answers are technically correct, but since "rise" is used as a noun, you should choose the word that matches.

Comment: I'm confused because someone told me i can't put 'the' before gerund (verb + ing). Do you mean I can put 'the' before gerund?

Comment: Of course you can. It's being used as a noun, so it can have an article in front of it. If you were in Spain, you could go to the running of the bulls. You might not like babies, because of all the crying. You can also put "the" in front of -ing words when they're used as adjectives - the crying baby; the running bull. (That being said, disappearing doesn't match the form of "rise", which is what I was trying to point you towards.)